# Deprecated: Required parameter $msg follows optional parameter $level in Log.php line 72

Tags: php

another code is with error below
Fatal error: Cannot declare class CI_Log, because the name is already in use in C:\xampp\htdocs\system\libraries\Log.php on line 27
error is here side >>>
[enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LGtP.jpg

class CI_Log {

```
    protected $_log_path;
    protected $_threshold   = 1;
    protected $_date_fmt    = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
    protected $_enabled = TRUE;
    protected $_levels  = array('ERROR' => '1', 'DEBUG' => '2',  'INFO' => '3', 'ALL' => '4');
```

Comment: Your second error implies that you have imported the module twice.  Perhaps you should use `require_once` instead of `require`.

Comment: Please ask only 1 question at a time as it makes it difficult to properly answer when you need to answer several parts.

Answer (score 0):

Do you see what the error is saying?  Once you supply a default value for a parameter (as in `$level = 'error'`), all the parameters after that must also have default values.  So, either move your `$msg` parameter to be first, or supply a default for it (`$msg=""`).

Comment: I made the correction more error back when I leave it like this                                    
  public function write_log($level = 'error', $msg ='error' , $php_error = false)

Comment: I can't tell what your sentence says, but that's the right way to write the function.